# How to have multiple contents in Master Page in ASP

Tags: html, asp.net, css, sharepoint-2013, contentplaceholder

I am having an dilemma and I hope I would be clarified here.

I have a master page which has one contentplaceholder that is used by every other subpage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><%: Page.Title %></title>

<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/adipoli.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<!-- <![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="theScripts/placeholders.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="theScripts/jquery.appear.js"></script>

<!-- default stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/footerLinks.css" />
<!-- end default stylesheets -->

<!-- if IE version 9 or less -->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
<!-- ################################################################################ -->
<!-- ###                                                                          ### -->
<!-- ### The below contents will be visible in every page unless otherwise stated ### -->
<!-- ###                                                                          ### -->
<!-- ################################################################################ -->
<!-- ### BEGIN LEFT SIDE MENU ### -->
<!-- ### END LEFT SIDE MENU ### -->
<!-- ### BEGIN TOP RIBBON ### -->
<div id="headerRibbon">
    <span id="socialIcons">
        <asp:HyperLink title="Compant Homepage" href="Default.aspx" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
            <asp:Image src="theImages/wmlogo.png" width="219" height="47" alt="Compant Medical Group Homepage" title="Compant Medical Group Homepage" runat="server" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </span>

    <div id="tSearch">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <input id="searchText" name="" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search Compant" />
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]><!--> 
            <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="searchText" size="40" placeholder="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <!--<![endif]--> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ### END TOP RIBBON ### -->

<!-- ### BEGIN BOTTOM RIBBON ### -->
<div id="strip">
</div>
<div id="footerRibbon" class="footerRibbon">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="copyRight" Text="© 2009-14 COMPANY"></asp:Label>
</div>
<!-- ### END BOTTOM RIBBON ### -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="theScripts/defaultScript.js"></script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Aboutus**:

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="about.aspx.cs" Inherits="about" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

</asp:Content>
```

**Contactus**:

```
<%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="contact" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

</asp:Content>
```

Here is a snapshot of what it will look like:

[image]

My question is, what if there are Webparts in the aboutus page which has it's own HTML code which I would like certain users to be able to edit. Will that be possible with the way I have my Master page set up? Or do I have to have separate contentplaceholder for each subpage to achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by `Webparts`? The content inside body tag is easily editable using this.

Comment: In SharePoint, there is Webparts which are pretty much editable contents. Can I add the Webparts inside the content placeholder?

Comment: Also, I would remove `form runat=server` from Master page and add it in specific page where ever needed

Comment: Didn't know that was possible. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I am not sure what `webparts` is. You should add `sharepoint` tag in question. You should be good as long as you want to add something in body tag. But remove `runat=server` from master page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create SharePoint master page which supports all sharepoint features (like ribbon) i would suggest you to take standard master page and change it instead of creating new master page from scratch.

Your current master page won't support web parts because you do not have all necessary javascripts,css files, controls,etc. included in it. For example you need to have `SPWebPartManager` control on your page to support web parts (which is included in standard master page).

After adding all necessary stuff the next step will be to add `WebPartZone` control to your page to allow end-users to add web parts to the page.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="Standard" ID="MainHeader" Title="loc:Main Header">
    <ZoneTemplate>
    </ZoneTemplate>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```